# replace mutiple files across various subfolders with a new version file in unix

Tags: php, shell, unix, sed, grep

I can find several examples of how to replace a string in multiple files using grep or sed, but I want replace old version of file with a new version.

For example I have a class file  **new1.class.php** in 10 different sub-folders and I want to replace all these new1.class.php with a new new1.class.php,

how can I do that?

Comment: I think you want `sed -i` (for in-place edit)?

Comment: not really, I simply want to replace whole file with new file instead of replacing a string in the file.

Comment: did you want to rename those?

Comment: what do you mean by `new new1.class.php` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` and just copy the new file over the top thusly...

```
find . -name new1.class.php -exec cp /some/place/new1.class.php {} \;
```

(Assuming you run this as root) `cp` will preserve the ownership and permission of the target file (the one being overwritten). If you want to keep the permissions of the source file then you can use `cp -p`

Comment: it will replace all of them with one

Comment: thanks, thats pretty much I was looking for. How about restoring the same user and permission to while which it originally had before replacing ?